# Laravel Forge deployment script fails with 'command not found'

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, npm, laravel-forge

**Quick explanation:** I have a staging and a production server, both with the same deployment script (the only difference is the repo branch the clone). The deployment script runs `bower install` which is globally installed on both servers.

To install it globally I changed `npm config set prefix` to `/home/forge/.npm-packages` and afterwards ran `npm install -g bower` (note `sudo` wasn't needed, that's the point of changing the prefix). Once again, this was done in both servers.

When I `ssh` into each server, and run `bower -v`, `which bower` it is clear the command DO exist, and it IS added to `PATH` env. It is the same output for both servers.

Manually running `bower install` on the project root works for both server.

The issue is the forge deployment script, which **only fails on production** (IKR? I don't know what was I expecting).

**The actual output is:**

```
/home/forge/.forge/provision-2394191.sh: line 8: bower: command not found
```

The interesting part is, in my attempt to debug, I manually ran `provision-2394191.sh` and it worked.

What is wrong with my production server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like adding the new `/home/forge/.npm-packages` to the `$PATH` using `export` was not enough. To solve this I had to manually add it to the `/etc/environment` file.

Comment: Worked like a charm !